# how to locate the below elements for css or xpath

Tags: css, xpath

I have below code and want to locate the element for css or xpath.

```
<div class="arrowIconDiv" data-dojo-attach-point="arrowIconDiv">
<div class="i-arrow-double" data-dojo-attach-point="NavAreaExpander">  /div>
<div class="i-arrow-double-hover" data-dojo-attach-point="NavAreaExpanderHover"></div>
```

Tried multiple things but was not able to locate and click on the element.

```
(by.css(".arrowIconDiv"))
(by.css('[data-dojo-attach-point="arrowIconDiv"]'))
(by.xpath('.//div[@class="i-arrow-double-hover"][.="NavAreaExpanderHover"]'))
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

`NavAreaExpanderHover` is value of `data-dojo-attach-point` attribute, not the content of the div element. So instead of using `.` in the XPath, use the attribute name :

```
.//div[@class="i-arrow-double-hover" and @data-dojo-attach-point="NavAreaExpanderHover"]
```

Comment: I tried the above and when i run the script, i can see still the element is not getting located. I am getting error "Clicking of element failed".

Comment: Also Tried (by.xpath('.//div[@class="arrowIconDiv" and @data-dojo-attach-point="arrowIconDiv"] , one time it worked later seeing warning as "more than one element found for locator ... "